# Pivot ItemsSource DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, pivot

Can I use a DataTemplate when I declare my PivotItems in the XAML directly?

I want to declare the items in the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem>
        <!--Content here-->
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

or if you want to use DataTemplate

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem Title="Title" Content="{Binding Content}"
               ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"/>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: So can I put <PivotItem> <PivotItem.DataTemplate> <DataTemplate> ? How would I then set the ContentTemplate to that ?  That is the way I would do it if I were Binding ItemsSource to something.

Comment: ContentTemplate = {Binding ItemTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} ?!?